# Eclipse Shift+Ctrl+O stopped functioning (Android 4.0.3)

Tags: android, eclipse

Using Eclipse's Shift+Ctrl+O to organize imports has been working fine until it stopped working.

For some reason, it is now taking away my necessary imports and causing classes to be unresolved. Example below, Button, onClick, Toast are not resolved due to when Shift-Ctrl-O was pressed, it cleaned out the needed file.

It was working before and I don't know what I did to cause it to not work anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I cleaned project, restart eclipse...to no avail.

```
final Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);          
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
        //Perform action on clicks
        Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuffActivity.this, "Beep Bop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 });
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: have you maybe switched the keyboard layout? try ALT + SHIFT a couple of times and test if it works

Comment: You might have multiple versions of jars in classpath. Have you installed anything recently?

Comment: It is `ctrl+shift+o` not `Shift+Ctrl+O` . Was that a typo?

Comment: This happens on occasion. Just restart Eclipse.

Comment: @CoolBeans Does the order matter?

Comment: @his - Your are right. It does not seem to matter. I thought it did. I stand corrected.

Comment: for me it was the amd driver, which overrided this hotkey globally, after killing amddrv.exe it started working again

Answer (score 1):

I have/had the same problem.  Best I could figure out is that eclipse need to have a 'source' item on the main tool bar which has has 'options' like format and 'Organize Imports'.  Clicking on a project in the "Package Explorer" causes the 'source' menu item to appear between 'refactor' and 'run'.

Comment: It didn't make Ctrl+Shift+O work but at least I can select it from that menu.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen when I created a file without a .java extension and renamed it with Refactor. Not until I noticed there was no syntax highlighting did I realize I still had it open in the text editor, so I closed it and reopened and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> started working again.